# Dealing with pointers when sorting an array in C

Tags: c, pointers, sorting

So I'm calling heapsort on an array in C.

My heapsort function looks like this:

```
void heapSort(int keys[], int numKeys){
...
int tmp[numKeys];
for(int i=0; i<numKeys; i++){
    tmp[i] = maxVaue(h);
    deleteMax(h);
}

*keys = tmp;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is change `keys` to point to the new array, as the function return type is void. Is there any way to do this with pointers, or do I need to just `memcpy` the array?

Comment: Arrays are not assignable, and you can't use `tmp` outside the function (it's out of scope when the function returns), so you need to use `memcpy()` anyways.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I just wanted to know if it was possible.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are not directly assignable, and also you can't use `tmp` outside the function, since it's out of scope when the function returns. You must use `memcpy()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change what `keys` points to, you'll have to declare it as `int **`. And use explicit dynamic allocation (use of `malloc`) rather than a C99 Variable-Length array.

Answer (score 1):

```
void heapSort(int **keys, int numKeys){
    int tmp = malloc(sizeof(int)*numKeys);
    ...
    free(*keys);
    *keys = tmp;
}

int main(){
    int *keys = malloc(sizeof(int)*numKeys);
    ...
    heapSort(&keys, numKeys)
}
```

Comment: Please consider [not casting the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169). Thanks.

Comment: ok,get it. thanks for the reminder